# React Native speed tracker google maps API

Tags: react-native, google-maps, expo, react-native-maps

First of all, I apologize if I don't post correctly, due to it's my first post ever in Stack Overflow.

Well, why am I here? I'm a software engineer and it's my first time working with react-native and I'm making an app that tracks the user by GPS, getting the speed and the traveled distance, however I'm desperate because I can't get the speed nor the distance traveled.

My code starts with a button to "start journey", which sets isTracking=true. and if you end the journey it sets isTracking=false. When isTracking=true, it gets the speed and traveled distance. Speed should be visible at all times.

I think i have a mess between many components and getting calls to user's location.

so well, this is my main component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';
import MapComponent from './MapComponent';
import DistanceComponent from './DistanceComponent';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
import { GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY } from '@env';
import TimeComponent from './TimeComponent';
import LocationSearchComponent from './LocationSearchComponent';
import VehiculoChooser from './VehiculoChooser';
import ButtonIniciarViaje from './ButtonIniciarViaje';
import TotalRouteCost from './TotalRouteCost';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import TimeComponentLive from './TimeComponentLive';
import DistanceComponentLive from './DistanceComponentLive';
import SpeedComponentLive from './SpeedComponentLive';
import TotalRouteCostLive from './TotalRouteCostLive';

const GPSDestination = ({ sucursal }) => {
  const [origin, setOrigin] = useState(null);
  const [destination, setDestination] = useState(null);
  const [distance, setDistance] = useState(null);
  const [time, setTime] = useState(null);
  const [initialLocation, setInitialLocation] = useState(null);
  const [vehiculoSeleccionado, setVehiculoSeleccionado] = useState(null);
  const [isTracking, setIsTracking] = useState(false);
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [mapRegion, setMapRegion] = useState(null);
  const [originMarkerColor, setOriginMarkerColor] = useState('red');
  const [elapsedTime, setElapsedTime] = useState(0);
  const [distanceTraveled, setDistanceTraveled] = useState(0);
  const [speed, setSpeed] = useState(0);
  const [previousLocation, setPreviousLocation] = useState(null);
  const [updateTimer, setUpdateTimer] = useState(null);
  const [costLive, setCostLive] = useState(null);
  const [locationSubscription, setLocationSubscription] = useState(null);
  const geolib = require('geolib');
  const [routeDetails, setRouteDetails] = useState({
    distance: null,
    duration: null,
    tolls: [],
  });
  const MIN_DISTANCE_UPDATE = 10;
  const UPDATE_INTERVAL = 5000;
  const MIN_SPEED_THRESHOLD = 0.27778;

  const handleStartTracking = async () => {
    console.log('Tracking started');
    setIsTracking(true);
    setInitialLocation(null); // Reiniciar la ubicación inicial al iniciar el rastreo
    setDistanceTraveled(0); // Restablecer la distancia cuando se inicia el rastreo
  };

  const handleStopTracking = () => {
    console.log('Tracking stopped');
    setIsTracking(false);
    setUpdateTimer(null);
    
    // Verifica si locationSubscription está definido antes de intentar limpiarlo
    if (locationSubscription && locationSubscription.remove) {
      console.log('Removing location subscription');
      locationSubscription.remove();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Console log 0");
    const getLocationOnAppStart = async () => {
      let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        console.error('Permission to access location was denied');
        return;
      }
      const location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
      setOrigin(location.coords);
      setPreviousLocation(location.coords); // Establecer la ubicación inicial como la anterior
    };

    getLocationOnAppStart();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Console log 1");
    let intervalId;
    if (isTracking) {
      intervalId = startTimer();
    } else {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId); // Limpiar el temporizador correctamente
  }, [isTracking]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Console log 1.5");
    if (isTracking) {
      setDistanceTraveled(0); // Establecer la distancia a cero cuando isTracking cambie a true
    }
  }, [isTracking]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Console log 2");
    console.log('Requesting location permission...');
    (async () => {
      let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        console.log('Permission to access location was denied');
        return;
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Console log 3");
    let subscription = null; // Inicializa la variable de suscripción
  
    const startLocationUpdates = async () => {
      let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        console.error('Permission to access location was denied');
        return;
      }
  
      const locationOptions = {
        accuracy: Location.Accuracy.BestForNavigation,
        timeInterval: 1000,
      };
  
      subscription = await Location.watchPositionAsync(locationOptions, (location) => {
        console.log('New location:', location.coords);
        console.log('Speed:', location.coords.speed); // Agregar console log de la velocidad
        if (!origin) {
          console.log('Setting initial origin:', location.coords);
          setOrigin(location.coords);
          setPreviousLocation(location.coords);
        } else if (isTracking && location.coords.speed > MIN_SPEED_THRESHOLD) { // Añadir condición de velocidad mínima
          const distance = calculateDistance(previousLocation, location.coords);
          console.log('Calculated distance:', distance);
          setDistanceTraveled(prevDistance => prevDistance + distance);
          setPreviousLocation(location.coords);
  
          if (distance >= MIN_DISTANCE_UPDATE && !updateTimer) {
            setUpdateTimer(setTimeout(() => {
              setUpdateTimer(null);
            }, UPDATE_INTERVAL));
          }
        }
      });
    };
  
    if (isTracking) {
      startLocationUpdates();
    } else {
      // Detener la suscripción si se detiene el rastreo
      if (subscription) {
        console.log('Removing location subscription');
        subscription.remove();
      }
      if (updateTimer) {
        clearTimeout(updateTimer);
        setUpdateTimer(null);
      }
    }
  
    return () => {
      // Limpiar las suscripciones y los temporizadores al desmontar el componente
      if (subscription) {
        console.log('Removing location subscription');
        subscription.remove();
      }
      if (updateTimer) {
        clearTimeout(updateTimer);
        setUpdateTimer(null);
      }
    };
  }, [isTracking, origin, previousLocation, updateTimer]);
  

  const calculateDistance = (previousCoords, currentCoords) => {
    if (!previousCoords || !currentCoords ||
      !previousCoords.latitude || !previousCoords.longitude ||
      !currentCoords.latitude || !currentCoords.longitude) {
      console.log('One or both coordinates are invalid:', { previousCoords, currentCoords });
      return 0;
    }
  
    try {
      const distanceTraveled = geolib.getDistance(
        { latitude: previousCoords.latitude, longitude: previousCoords.longitude },
        { latitude: currentCoords.latitude, longitude: currentCoords.longitude }
      );
      return distanceTraveled;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error calculating distance:', error);
      return 0;
    }
  };

  const startTimer = () => {
    return setInterval(() => {
      setElapsedTime(prevTime => prevTime + 1); // Incrementa el tiempo transcurrido en 1 segundo
    }, 1000); // Llama a la función cada segundo
  };

  const stopTimer = (intervalId) => {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  };

  const fetchDetails = async (placeId) => {
    try {
      const resp = await fetch(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=${placeId}&key=${GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY}`);
      const data = await resp.json();
      return data.result;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching location details:', error);
      return null;
    }
  };

  const handleSelectVehiculo = (vehiculo) => {
    setVehiculoSeleccionado(vehiculo);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Console log 4");
    console.log('Requesting location permission...');
    (async () => {
      let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        console.log('Permission to access location was denied');
        return;
      }

      let currentLocation = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
      setOrigin(currentLocation.coords);
    })();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Console log 5");
    if (origin && destination) {
      calculateDistance();
    }
  }, [origin, destination, vehiculoSeleccionado]);

  useEffect(() => {
    //busca informacion con fetch cuando origin y destination están disponibles en el mapa
    console.log("Console log 5.5");
    if (origin && destination) {
      fetchRouteDetails();
    }
  }, [origin, destination]);

  const fetchRouteDetails = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=${origin.latitude},${origin.longitude}&destination=${destination.latitude},${destination.longitude}&key=${GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY}`
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      if (data.status === 'OK') {
        const totalDistance = data.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text;
        const totalDuration = data.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text;
        const tollsInfo = data.routes[0].legs[0].steps.filter(step => step.toll);
        setRouteDetails({
          distance: totalDistance,
          duration: totalDuration,
          tolls: tollsInfo,
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching directions:', error);
    }
  };

  const onSelectDestination = (coords) => {
    setDestination(coords);
  };

  const handleLocationChange = (location) => {
    const calculatedSpeed = location.coords.speed;
    if (calculatedSpeed !== null && !isNaN(calculatedSpeed)) {
      setSpeed(calculatedSpeed);
    } else {
      setSpeed(0);
    }
    setPreviousLocation(location.coords);
  };
  

  const handleVehiculoSeleccionado = (vehiculo) => {
    setVehiculoSeleccionado(vehiculo);
  };

  const onMapLayout = () => {
    // Implementa tu lógica para el diseño del mapa si es necesario
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <LocationSearchComponent
        key="LocationSearchComponent"
        onSelectLocation={onSelectDestination}
        fetchDetails={fetchDetails}
      />
      <MapComponent
        key="MapComponent"
        origin={origin}
        destination={destination}
        onLocationChange={handleLocationChange}
        setOrigin={setOrigin}
        setDestination={setDestination}
        onMapLayout={onMapLayout}
        initialRegion={mapRegion}
        onStartTracking={handleStartTracking}
        isTracking={isTracking}
        setOriginMarkerColor={setOriginMarkerColor}
        tolls={routeDetails.tolls} // Pasa los detalles de la ruta como prop
      />

      <Text style={[styles.title, styles.bottomBorder]}>Datos estimados</Text>
      <View style={styles.containerData}>
        <TimeComponent key="TimeComponent" time={routeDetails.duration || ''} />
        <DistanceComponent key="DistanceComponent" distance={routeDetails.distance} />
        <TotalRouteCost key="TotalRouteCost" sucursal={sucursal} distance={routeDetails.distance} time={routeDetails.duration} vehiculoSeleccionado={vehiculoSeleccionado} />
      </View>

      <Text style={[styles.title, styles.bottomBorder]}>Datos en tiempo real</Text>
      <View style={styles.containerData}>
        {isTracking && <TimeComponentLive time={elapsedTime} />}
        {isTracking && <DistanceComponentLive distanceTraveled={distanceTraveled} />}
        <SpeedComponentLive speed={speed} />
        {isTracking && <TotalRouteCostLive distanceTraveled={distanceTraveled} elapsedTime={elapsedTime} sucursal={sucursal} vehiculoSeleccionado={vehiculoSeleccionado} />}
      </View>

      <VehiculoChooser onSelectVehiculo={handleSelectVehiculo} />
      <View style={styles.containerButtons}>
        {origin && destination && (
          <ButtonIniciarViaje onPress={isTracking ? handleStopTracking : handleStartTracking} isTracking={isTracking} />
        )}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  containerData: {
    marginTop: 10,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  containerButtons: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    marginTop: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
    gap: 5,
  },
  bottomBorder: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    width: '90%',
    borderBottomWidth: 0.8,
    borderBottomColor: 'grey',
    alignSelf: 'center',
  },
  title: {
    marginTop: 10,
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginBottom: 0,
  },
});

export default GPSDestination;
```

I really hope you guys can help me, i'm having a lot of trouble with this.

Also, this is an error I keep getting:

> ERROR  Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.

Please I need some guidance, I'm sure my code is a mess, and it grew so much that I can't find the problem!

Also, this is some log I get:

```
LOG  New location: {"accuracy": 3.9000000953674316, "altitude": 0, "altitudeAccuracy": 0, "heading": 129.13783264160156, "latitude": -41.31685561664034, "longitude": -73.01744943150514, "speed": 1.3888888359069824}
 LOG  Speed: 1.3888888359069824
 LOG  Calculated distance: 19
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3

 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  New location: {"accuracy": 3.9000000953674316, "altitude": 0, "altitudeAccuracy": 0, "heading": 129.13783264160156, "latitude": -41.31685561664034, "longitude": -73.01744943150514, "speed": 1.3888888359069824}
 LOG  Speed: 1.3888888359069824
 LOG  Calculated distance: 19
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  New location: {"accuracy": 3.9000000953674316, "altitude": 0, "altitudeAccuracy": 0, "heading": 129.13783264160156, "latitude": -41.31685561664034, "longitude": -73.01744943150514, "speed": 1.3888888359069824}
 LOG  Speed: 1.3888888359069824
 LOG  Calculated distance: 19
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  New location: {"accuracy": 3.9000000953674316, "altitude": 0, "altitudeAccuracy": 0, "heading": 129.13783264160156, "latitude": -41.31685561664034, "longitude": -73.01744943150514, "speed": 1.3888888359069824}
 LOG  Speed: 1.3888888359069824
 LOG  Calculated distance: 19
 
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  New location: {"accuracy": 3.9000000953674316, "altitude": 0, "altitudeAccuracy": 0, "heading": 129.13783264160156, "latitude": -41.3168627365243, "longitude": -73.01743782653836, "speed": 1.3888888359069824}
 LOG  Speed: 1.3888888359069824
 LOG  Calculated distance: 21
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  New location: {"accuracy": 3.9000000953674316, "altitude": 0, "altitudeAccuracy": 0, "heading": 129.13783264160156, "latitude": -41.3168627365243, "longitude": -73.01743782653836, "speed": 1.3888888359069824}
 LOG  Speed: 1.3888888359069824
 LOG  Calculated distance: 20
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  New location: {"accuracy": 3.9000000953674316, "altitude": 0, "altitudeAccuracy": 0, "heading": 129.13783264160156, "latitude": -41.3168627365243, "longitude": -73.01743782653836, "speed": 1.3888888359069824}
 LOG  Speed: 1.3888888359069824
 LOG  Calculated distance: 21
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  New location: {"accuracy": 3.9000000953674316, "altitude": 0, "altitudeAccuracy": 0, "heading": 129.13783264160156, "latitude": -41.3168627365243, "longitude": -73.01743782653836, "speed": 1.3888888359069824}
 LOG  Speed: 1.3888888359069824
 LOG  Calculated distance: 20
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  New location: {"accuracy": 3.9000000953674316, "altitude": 0, "altitudeAccuracy": 0, "heading": 129.13783264160156, "latitude": -41.3168627365243, "longitude": -73.01743782653836, "speed": 1.3888888359069824}
 LOG  Speed: 1.3888888359069824
 LOG  Calculated distance: 21
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  New location: {"accuracy": 3.9000000953674316, "altitude": 0, "altitudeAccuracy": 0, "heading": 129.13783264160156, "latitude": -41.3168627365243, "longitude": -73.01743782653836, "speed": 1.3888888359069824}
 LOG  Speed: 1.3888888359069824
 LOG  Calculated distance: 20
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  New location: {"accuracy": 3.9000000953674316, "altitude": 0, "altitudeAccuracy": 0, "heading": 129.13783264160156, "latitude": -41.316869943218485, "longitude": -73.01742608007632, "speed": 1.3888888359069824}
 LOG  Speed: 1.3888888359069824
 LOG  Calculated distance: 22
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  New location: {"accuracy": 3.9000000953674316, "altitude": 0, "altitudeAccuracy": 0, "heading": 129.13783264160156, "latitude": -41.316869943218485, "longitude": -73.01742608007632, "speed": 1.3888888359069824}
 LOG  Speed: 1.3888888359069824
 LOG  Calculated distance: 22
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  New location: {"accuracy": 3.9000000953674316, "altitude": 0, "altitudeAccuracy": 0, "heading": 129.13783264160156, "latitude": -41.316869943218485, "longitude": -73.01742608007632, "speed": 1.3888888359069824}
 LOG  Speed: 1.3888888359069824
 LOG  Calculated distance: 22
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  New location: {"accuracy": 3.9000000953674316, "altitude": 0, "altitudeAccuracy": 0, "heading": 129.13783264160156, "latitude": -41.316869943218485, "longitude": -73.01742608007632, "speed": 1.3888888359069824}
 LOG  Speed: 1.3888888359069824
 LOG  Calculated distance: 22
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  New location: {"accuracy": 3.9000000953674316, "altitude": 0, "altitudeAccuracy": 0, "heading": 129.13783264160156, "latitude": -41.316869943218485, "longitude": -73.01742608007632, "speed": 1.3888888359069824}
 LOG  Speed: 1.3888888359069824
 LOG  Calculated distance: 22
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  New location: {"accuracy": 3.9000000953674316, "altitude": 0, "altitudeAccuracy": 0, "heading": 129.13783264160156, "latitude": -41.316869943218485, "longitude": -73.01742608007632, "speed": 1.3888888359069824}
 LOG  Speed: 1.3888888359069824
 LOG  Calculated distance: 22
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  New location: {"accuracy": 3.9000000953674316, "altitude": 0, "altitudeAccuracy": 0, "heading": 129.13783264160156, "latitude": -41.316869943218485, "longitude": -73.01742608007632, "speed": 1.3888888359069824}
 LOG  Speed: 1.3888888359069824
 LOG  Calculated distance: 22
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  New location: {"accuracy": 3.9000000953674316, "altitude": 0, "altitudeAccuracy": 0, "heading": 129.13783264160156, "latitude": -41.316869943218485, "longitude": -73.01742608007632, "speed": 1.3888888359069824}
 LOG  Speed: 1.3888888359069824
 LOG  Calculated distance: 22
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  New location: {"accuracy": 3.9000000953674316, "altitude": 0, "altitudeAccuracy": 0, "heading": 129.13783264160156, "latitude": -41.316869943218485, "longitude": -73.01742608007632, "speed": 1.3888888359069824}
 LOG  Speed: 1.3888888359069824
 LOG  Calculated distance: 22
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  New location: {"accuracy": 3.9000000953674316, "altitude": 0, "altitudeAccuracy": 0, "heading": 129.13783264160156, "latitude": -41.316869943218485, "longitude": -73.01742608007632, "speed": 1.3888888359069824}
 LOG  Speed: 1.3888888359069824
 LOG  Calculated distance: 22
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 ERROR  Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.      
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  New location: {"accuracy": 3.9000000953674316, "altitude": 0, "altitudeAccuracy": 0, "heading": 129.13783264160156, "latitude": -41.316869943218485, "longitude": -73.01742608007632, "speed": 1.3888888359069824}
 LOG  Speed: 1.3888888359069824
 LOG  Calculated distance: 22
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  New location: {"accuracy": 3.9000000953674316, "altitude": 0, "altitudeAccuracy": 0, "heading": 129.13783264160156, "latitude": -41.316869943218485, "longitude": -73.01742608007632, "speed": 1.3888888359069824}
 LOG  Speed: 1.3888888359069824
 LOG  Calculated distance: 22
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  New location: {"accuracy": 3.9000000953674316, "altitude": 0, "altitudeAccuracy": 0, "heading": 129.13783264160156, "latitude": -41.316869943218485, "longitude": -73.01742608007632, "speed": 1.3888888359069824}
 LOG  Speed: 1.3888888359069824
 LOG  Calculated distance: 22
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  New location: {"accuracy": 3.9000000953674316, "altitude": 0, "altitudeAccuracy": 0, "heading": 129.13783264160156, "latitude": -41.31687709468896, "longitude": -73.01741442362548, "speed": 1.3888888359069824}
 LOG  Speed: 1.3888888359069824
 LOG  Calculated distance: 23
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  New location: {"accuracy": 3.9000000953674316, "altitude": 0, "altitudeAccuracy": 0, "heading": 129.13783264160156, "latitude": -41.31687709468896, "longitude": -73.01741442362548, "speed": 1.3888888359069824}
 LOG  Speed: 1.3888888359069824
 LOG  Calculated distance: 23
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  New location: {"accuracy": 3.9000000953674316, "altitude": 0, "altitudeAccuracy": 0, "heading": 129.13783264160156, "latitude": -41.31687709468896, "longitude": -73.01741442362548, "speed": 1.3888888359069824}
 LOG  Speed: 1.3888888359069824
 LOG  Calculated distance: 23
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  New location: {"accuracy": 3.9000000953674316, "altitude": 0, "altitudeAccuracy": 0, "heading": 129.13783264160156, "latitude": -41.31687709468896, "longitude": -73.01741442362548, "speed": 1.3888888359069824}
 LOG  Speed: 1.3888888359069824
 LOG  Calculated distance: 23
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 
 LOG  New location: {"accuracy": 3.9000000953674316, "altitude": 0, "altitudeAccuracy": 0, "heading": 129.13783264160156, "latitude": -41.31688432508056, "longitude": -73.01740263853813, "speed": 1.3888888359069824}
 LOG  Speed: 1.3888888359069824
 LOG  Calculated distance: 24
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  New location: {"accuracy": 3.9000000953674316, "altitude": 0, "altitudeAccuracy": 0, "heading": 129.13783264160156, "latitude": -41.31688432508056, "longitude": -73.01740263853813, "speed": 1.3888888359069824}
 LOG  Speed: 1.3888888359069824
 LOG  Calculated distance: 24
 LOG  Console log 3
 LOG  Console log 3
```

thank you very much guys, I hope you can enlighten me!

I tried moving the code that calculates speed and distance traveled to their own components but I made it worse